# Animation and MVC principle

Tags: oop, model-view-controller, design-patterns, animation

I always design my programs according to MVC principle, but fitting animation in is pain-in-the-ass.

I have implemented following scheme so far:

1) Model does number of actions [] and sends notifications to all listeners;

2) Upon reciving a notification View adds an animation to the queue.

It's workable approach, but it has one huge drawback — model and UI become unsyncronized. For example there are 10 actions already applied to the model, but UI is still in state, where 5 of them are applied.

This drawback forces animations to be coded uninterruptable, which is not good practice for UI design. Please, suggest how to resolve the issue.

Comment: For now just moved action trigger to View. Doesn't seem right at all, but unfortunatelly it is the only way everything works.

Answer (score 1):

You could update your model **after** the animation finished. This way, your animations are a representation that the user can use to determine when an actions is finished. E.g. after dragging an object to its destination, the object remains (model-side) on its old location until the animation finishes, only then is it moved to the new one.

That way, if the animation fails because the user interrupts it or an error ocurrs, your model will still be synchronized with the current state of your view.

Comment: It's not the case. In my case, model is a source of a series of actions (by timer, for example). And I want model to do next action only after animation is complete.